# Too frequently rolling logs for repartition topic results in out of memory in machine running kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-streams

The repartition topic is rollig the logs too quickly, and we are pretty sure that his causes the machine to run out of memory. This happens when we reprocess a topic with a lot of messages, when we have updated some part of our streams-app that makes it require a reprocess. The input topic contains messages with timestamps up to two years back.

This worked with the old version of streams (1.0.1) but then the repartion topics will not get cleaned up fast enough instead.

The topic settings:

```
kafka-topics.sh --topic my_state_store-repartition --describe 
Topic:my_state_store-repartition    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:segment.bytes=52428800,retention.ms=9223372036854775807,segment.index.bytes=52428800,cleanup.policy=delete,segment.ms=600000
    Topic: my_state_store-repartition   Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

Kafka log | tail :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000100560000, 131072, 0) failed; error='Out of memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 131072 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid1.log
```

One of the state stores repartion logs folder.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-159:~$ sudo ls -l -h /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volumeId>/_data/kafka-logs/my_state_store-repartition-0 |tail -n100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873778.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873778.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873778.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    16 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873788.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   46K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873788.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873788.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    24 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873788.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873814.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873814.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873814.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873814.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    16 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873821.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   45K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873821.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873821.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    24 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873821.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    16 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873846.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   46K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873846.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873846.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    24 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873846.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873873.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873873.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873873.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873873.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873881.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873881.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873881.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873881.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873890.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873890.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873890.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873890.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873899.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873899.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873899.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873899.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873908.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873908.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873908.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873908.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873917.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873917.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873917.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873917.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873927.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873927.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873927.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873927.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873937.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873937.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873937.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873937.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873957.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873957.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873957.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873957.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873967.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873967.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873967.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873967.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873977.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873977.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873977.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873977.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873987.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873987.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873987.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873987.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873997.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873997.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873997.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011873997.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874016.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   32K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874016.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874016.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874016.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874034.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   31K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874034.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874034.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874034.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874052.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874052.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874052.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874052.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874061.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   15K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874061.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874061.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874061.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874070.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874070.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874070.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874070.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874086.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874086.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874086.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    12 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874086.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50M Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874095.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  265K Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874095.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10 Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874095.snapshot
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50M Oct  9 13:43 00000000000011874095.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    14 Oct  9 13:42 leader-epoch-checkpoint
```

The issue has to do with the "segment.ms=600000" setting. Which is based on the timestamp, not walltime. The problem is solved when changing to segment.ms to Long.max(), and then only roll when segment has 50mb. Then the question becomes how to change the settings of the repartition topics. It can be done manually with kafka-topic.sh but this is unsustainable with a lot of different apps, and needing to reset them when we change the way it aggregates. And from what i understand i can't change the settings for repartition topics with kafka-streams? Or even better would be some kind of minimum time for segment rolling to prevent or similar?

EDIT1: Seems like i misunderstood segment.ms, It is the maximum difference between timestamps within the segment.(?) Setting it long.max is a bit unnecessary, our problems are solved when setting it to 30days and should work with even shorter segment sizes as well.

Comment: You can actually change the topic config using `topic.` prefix and add the config to you application configuration. For example `put("topic.segment.ms", ...)` -- note, that topic configs will only be applied if a topic is newly created. The config of existing topic will not be updated.

Comment: That affects all the topics right? There is no way to only modify the repartition topics, or even better the ones that inherit the timestamp from the inputs.

Comment: Correct. If you only want to change the config for some topics, you will need to do it manually after they got created.

Comment: So after further research it seams the standard settings for repartition topics were changed in 2.3.0 and they now use the default (7 days) segment.ms instead of the 10 minutes that was in 2.0 . This means the issue is resolved for us. Should i remove the question or do you think it could be useful for someone?

Comment: Ah. Yes. That's correct. No need to delete the question IMHO. Maybe answer your own question and accept your own answer to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue for version 2.0, the standard settings for repartition topics had segment.ms set. This caused instant rolling when you reprocessed old messages. In newer versions this config is not set, which solved our issues.

Ps. Thx @Mathias J. Sax for the comments!